# triangles and lines

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 12 points in a plane. If 4 of them are on a straight line and no other 3 points are on a straight line, then find the difference between the number of triangles and the number of straight lines that can be formed using these points.

A. 215  B. 216  C. 156  D. 155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Find the number of cases when no $3$ points are collinear. Then subtract the *wrong* cases.

Number of triangles : $ ^{12}C_3-{} ^4C_3$ // simply subtract all cases when you counted all 3 collinear points

Number of lines : $^{12}C_2-{}^4C_2+1$ // you have subtracted the cases where you took the 2 points of in same line but that is also a line. You again add 1.

Comment: I'll try and write. thank you

Comment: @vickyace Did you do it?

Comment: I keep getting 160. but the answer is 155

Comment: I will edit....

Comment: @vickyace Done.

Comment: brilliant. i thank you. the concept is clear now

Comment: @vickyace You must accept the answer if problem has been resolved. Click on the tick mark

Comment: it was my first time. I didn't know we could do that. won't happen again. but thanks again. :-)

Comment: @vickyace No need to panic. You are welcome.